# How to find text in Cypress when value attribute is not given?

Tags: cypress

I have Three text-boxes. Input 10 in first text-box and you will get 9.5 and 10.5 in next 2 text-boxes. Need to verify the values of auto calculated text-boxes.

1. This is the application
   [image]
2. This is what i Have tried

   - cy.get('#LSL').should('have.text', '9.5');
   - cy.get('#LSL').should('contains', '9.5');
3. Issue that I am getting is 
   [image]

text that it finds is blank

Comment: So what is actually the issue here? What code have you tried?

Comment: Can you just find this box via ID and validate using `contain` if it is ok? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi @voy , I have edited the question. Thanks In advance

Comment: Hi @mvoase, issue is that i cant verfiy the text in textbox. Edited the question above. Please Have a look

Comment: Can you inspect further? I’m wondering if it is not in the text - it could be part of innerText or something

Comment: @MirzaAsimBaig Is that issue solved now ?

Comment: @soccerway Yes issue is resolve with cy.get('#LSL').invoke('val').should('contain', 9.5)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```html
cy.get('#LSL').invoke('val').should('contain', 9.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the value attribute is not present for any input field, the next is to look for for innerHTML or innerText. Mind giving this a try:

```
cy.get('#LSL').invoke('text').should('contain', 9.5);
```